# Wanting to limit Threadpool so it doesn't max out CPU

Tags: c#, threadpool, portable-class-library

I am programming with Threads for the first time. My program only shows a small amount of data at a time; as the user moves through the data I want it to load all the possible data that could be access next so there is as little lag as possible when user switches to a new section.

Worst case scenario I might need to preload 6 sections of data. So I use something like:

```
if (SectionOne == null)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new System.Threading.WaitCallback(PreloadSection),
        Tuple.Create(thisSection, SectionOne));
}
if (SectionTwo == null)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new System.Threading.WaitCallback(PreloadSection),
        Tuple.Create(thisSection, SectionTwo));
}
//....
```

to preload each area.  It works great on my main system that has 8 cores; but on my test system that only has 4 cores the entire system slows to a crawl while it is running the threads.

I am thinking that I want to run a maximum of TotalCores - 2 threads at the same time. But really I have no idea.

Looking for any help in getting this to run as efficiently as possible on multiple system setups  (single core through 8 cores or whatever). Also, I am using C# and this is a Portable Class Library project, so some of my options are limited.

Answer (score 0):

I would be using this built in .NET parallelism magic.

[Task Parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx)

With the Task operations that is managed for you but you still have control to pick how many cores and threads you want.

Example:

```
const int MAX = 10000;

var options = new ParallelOptions
{
   MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2
};


IList<int> threadIds = new List<int>();
Parallel.For(0, MAX, options, i =>
{

   var id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
   Console.WriteLine("Number '{0}' on thread {1}", i, id);
                    threadIds.Add(id);
});
```

You can even do it with Extensions if you want:

```
const int MAX_TASKS = 8;

var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000000);

IList<int> threadIds = new List<int>(MAX_TASKS);
numbers.AsParallel()
       .WithDegreeOfParallelism(MAX_TASKS)
       .ForAll(i =>
        {
           var id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
           if (!threadIds.Contains(id))
           {
               threadIds.Add(id);
           }
        });

 Assert.IsTrue(threadIds.Count > 2);
 Assert.IsTrue(threadIds.Count <= MAX_TASKS);
 Console.WriteLine(threadIds.Count);
```

Comment: Thanks, good info. Maybe I am looking in the wrong place but this does not appear to be supported by Portable Class Libraries which is a constraint I am currently working with.

Comment: Looking at the link for Parallel.For here is what it supports:

Version Information
.NET Framework
Supported in: 4.5, 4
.NET Framework Client Profile
Supported in: 4
Portable Class Library
Supported in: Portable Class Library
.NET for Windows Store apps
Supported in: Windows 8

Comment: Those items are often wrong I have noticed -- or at least limiting -- for Portable Class Libraries.  It could be the Silverlight or Windows Phone 8 requirement that I have selected in the PCL that is causing the issue; but it not available in my program.

Comment: Gotcha. Well I tried. :) Too bad to because that library is magical.

Comment: I appreciate it and will keep it in mind for future projects!